# Capybara button.click works on Console but not on a Script (Ruby; Capybara; Poltergeist)

Tags: ruby, console, capybara, poltergeist

When I do this on PRY Console:

```
require 'phantomjs'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, :phantomjs => Phantomjs.path)
end

s = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist)
s.visit('site')
s.fill_in('field', with: data)
s.find_button('button').trigger('click')
```

It works as expected.

But when I try to do the same on a ruby file, script, it fails.

**Edit:** Why I say it fails, I mean that the form is not submitted and therefore the page wont redirect.

Does anybody know why?

Thanks

David

Comment: How does it fail? (what's the error you get, etc)

Comment: @ThomasWalpole, I have edited the post.

Comment: But how do you know it's not submitting -- you have to be getting an error somewhere?? What code are you running after the code you've shown that shows there is an error?  Also, running it in the PRY console of what code makes it work?  You really need to provide enough info so that we can see what might be creating an error.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I was using s.html to check if the html had change.
I'm made some test now and even thorough s.html looks the same, when I use the command s.find("#id") I get the expected result.

Anyways on "pry", s.html was showing the updated html.

I'm ESL, sorry.

Comment: You can't just use `s.html` immediately after the `trigger('click')` because the page hadn't actually been loaded yet.  If you put a `sleep(3)` after the trigger and then looked at s.html it would probably be correct.  Your `s.find("#id")` automatically waits up to `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` seconds for the element to appear so it is giving the page time to load

Comment: @ThomasWalpole thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `s.find_button('button').trigger('click')` the mouse click occurs and it immediately returns to your code while the "browser" goes off and starts requesting the next page or whatever action the click triggers. So if you immediately call `s.html` it's not going to be correct since the page hasn't actually loaded at that point in time.  You can either `sleep` for a few seconds to let the page load, or use the Capybara finders/matchers which will automatically wait (up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds) until the relevant elements appear (which means they wait for the page to load). It worked in the `pry` console because you were waiting just by the delay in typing the next command.